# Rails, deleting from grid works, but I get a weird exception

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, wice-grid

I have created a grid with the wice_grid gem and I am trying to add a delete button on every entry.

My html is the following:

```
<%= grid(@business_grid) do |g|

  g.column name: 'ID' do  |business|
    business.id
  end

  g.column name: 'Title' do |business|
    business.title
  end

  g.column name: 'Description' do |business|
    business.description
  end

  g.column name: 'PlayStore URL' do |business|
    business.playstore_url
  end  

 g.column name: 'AppStore URL' do |business|
   business.appstore_url
 end

 g.column do |business|


   link_to "Delete", {:controller=>"businesses", :action=>"delete_business",:business=>business.id}


 end

end -%>
```

Any in my controller:

```
class BusinessesController < ApplicationController


def create

    @business = Business.new(:title => params[:title], :description => params[:description], 
        :playstore_url => params[:playstore_url], :appstore_url => params[:appstore_url])
      if @business.save

        render json: { status: 'success' }  
      else
        render json: { status: 'error', errors: @business.errors.full_messages }
      end

end

def destroy

    @business = Business.find(params[:id])
    @business.destroy
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html {  render :partial => 'businessPartial'}
          format.xml  { head :ok }

        end

end



end
```

The delete function actually works, it does indeed delete the item, but then I get an ActionController Exception saying that the object can't be found

It seems to me like I delete it and then search for it again, but I don't understand why. Here's a screenshot of what I get when I click on the Delete link. [image: screenshot]
When I refresh the item is gone, which means that the delete function works.

I tried searching but I found nothing so specific.
Any help appreciated.

**Edit** My development.log file after only pressing the delete button:

> Started DELETE "/businesses/44" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-04-15 11:33:34
>   +0300   [1m[36mActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.3ms)[0m  [1mSELECT `schema_migrations`.* FROM `schema_migrations`[0m
>   Processing by BusinessesController#destroy as JS   Parameters:
>   {"id"=>"44"}   [1m[35mBusiness Load (0.4ms)[0m  SELECT 
>   `businesses`.* FROM `businesses` WHERE `businesses`.`id` = 44 LIMIT 1 
>   [1m[36m (0.1ms)[0m  [1mBEGIN[0m   [1m[35mSQL (0.5ms)[0m 
>   DELETE FROM `businesses` WHERE `businesses`.`id` = 44   [1m[36m
>   (10.1ms)[0m  [1mCOMMIT[0m Redirected to
>   http://localhost:3000admin_users/dashboard Completed 302 Found in 49ms
>   (ActiveRecord: 12.6ms)
>
> Started DELETE "/businesses/44" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-04-15 11:33:34
>   +0300 Processing by BusinessesController#destroy as JS   Parameters: {"id"=>"44"}   [1m[35mBusiness Load (0.3ms)[0m  SELECT 
>   `businesses`.* FROM `businesses` WHERE `businesses`.`id` = 44 LIMIT 1
>   Completed 404 Not Found in 16ms (ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)
>
> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Business with 'id'=44):
>   app/controllers/businesses_controller.rb:19:in `destroy'
>
> Rendered
>   /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb
>   (3.9ms)   Rendered
>   /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.text.erb (0.7ms)   Rendered
>   /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.text.erb
>   (0.9ms)   Rendered
>   /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.text.erb
>   (19.1ms)

I initalize the @business_gird in the controller of my view (called dashboard)

```
def dashboard
      @substore_grid = initialize_grid(Substore)
      @business_grid = initialize_grid(Business)
      @user_grid = initialize_grid(User)

  end
```

rake routes screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Why are you rendering the partial after destroying it?

Comment: And one more thing that is the way you are deleting the record is totally wrong. Needs to set routes for delete with method delete and the id you are passing in business that's very bad.

Comment: My businessPartial is the partial which contains the grid with all the businesses.
So I am deleting just an entry on the grid

Comment: @Bharatsoni, I am sorry, I'm a complete beginner, can you be more specific on what is bad? I would like to hear your suggestions.

Comment: You're code is not "completely wrong" -- it's simply different.  One of the key mantras of Rails is "convention over configuration".  The Rails convention for CRUD (create/read/update/delete) is to use the Rails conventions for a REST interface.  I would suggest taking a look into this practice as it WILL help simplify your work in Rails.  Especially as a beginner, it is easier to work within the "happy path" of the framework.  Check out the rails guide on routing for some help http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: ^ That said, how are you populating the @business_grid variable?  It needs to be populated for the partial to be rendered.  If you are using a before_action to retrieve the businesses then that could be the issue -- retrieving one set of records and then deleting one of the items in a separate db transaction immediately after.

Comment: @AndyV Hey andy thank you for replying. I updated the code with my whole BusinessesController. As you can see I have no other reference there about my business_grid variable. I'm not sure if that's what you were talking about, but please take a look.

Comment: @AndyV could it be because I haven't initialized the grid in my controller?

Comment: Yes, the controllers will map the instance variables (e.g., @business_grid) of the controller into your view rendering context.  Since you specifically reference @business_grid in your partial but have not initialized it in your view then I anticipate that you'll get a nil object error.

Comment: The answer will be in the logs. I recommend you do the following - run the app in development mode, browse to page with the delete button, stop the server. rename log/development.log as log/development.log.old, restart the server, then click on delete button. Stop the server. The new development log will contain only the output for the process causing the problem. Post that log here, and I think we should be able to work out what is going on.

Comment: @ReggieB, I did what you said and I added the development.log file into the original post. Also, thank you for letting me learning that way of troubleshooting.

Comment: @AndyV If I get a nil object error, then why does the delete function work? Also I do initialize business_grid. I updated the original post with it on the bottom.

Comment: The problem is here `Redirected to http://localhost:3000admin_users/dashboard Completed 302 Found in 49ms (ActiveRecord: 12.6ms)` For some reason `admin_users/dashboard` is redirecting you back to the action. Can you do `rake routes` and post the output.

Comment: @ReggieB Thank you Reggie. I added it in the original post.

Comment: Hm, based on the logs it looks like you're sending the delete request and expecting to process it as 'JS'.  See the end of this line? "Started DELETE "/businesses/44" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-04-15 11:33:34 +0300 Processing by BusinessesController#destroy as JS"  The end of the line "...as JS" is telling you that the controller believes that the format is "JS".  You'll need a 'format.js' block in your destroy method; depending on what the javascript is doing on the page, it's quite possible that what you have in format.html will suffice.

Comment: @AndyV Thanks for everything, but Kalman's answer is the solution. Really appreciate your effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that your 'businessPartial' partial is trying to use your `@business` variable which got deleted

```
format.html {  render :partial => 'businessPartial'}
```

Do you get the error when you remove this line?

Comment: I solved it earlier today, but still your guess was correct. I had also some other minor mistakes, but this was the root of all evil. Thank you anyway.